# Limit number of labels in Kendo-UI chart

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to limit the number of labels in the categoryAxis of my kendo chart.

So far I've calculated an automatic step from the number of data points and the width of the chart and it's worked great. But I'm starting to receive some data that triggers Kendo's automatic date label format switch to minutes and now I have 60 times more labels than I should, which creates huge amounts of lag (and makes the chart unreadable).

I've looked into setting a maxDateGroup, but that actually reduces the number of categories, thus ignoring some of the data.

I found [a way](https://www.telerik.com/forums/limiting-number-of-labels-in-categoryaxis) to get the number of labels on kendo's forums :

```html
    // get reference to the chart widget
    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
    // get the categories length
    chart._plotArea.categoryAxis.children.length
```

But it requires to draw the chart first, then read the property, then adjust accordingly and redraw the chart. Which isn't exactly ideal.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to set a max number of labels, or maybe limit labels to 1 per category ? Or any other trick-shot really :)

Note : this automatic switch works great for data that actually is recorded every minutes, but the series that's causing me problems is recorded every 30 minutes. Maybe there is some workaround here but I can't recall where I saw how to fiddle with these properties.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same problem and fine-tuned the labels with the following settings:

1. I set [categoryAxis.labels.step](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.labels#categoryaxislabelsstep) to 2 to only render every other label
2. I set [categoryAxis.labels.rotation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.labels#categoryaxislabelsrotation) to "auto" so longer labels are shown in diagonal
3. I set the [categoryAxis.labels.dateFormats](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.labels#categoryaxislabelsdateformats) to shorter ones, like `milliseconds: "dd.MM yyyy",`
4. I set [categoryAxis.maxDateGroups](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.maxdategroups) to `Math.floor(container.width() / 200) * 10`

All of this is assuming I have `categoryAxis.baseUnit` set to `"fit"`, since I can't assume much about my data.

Comment: This will indeed limit the number of labels but as stated in the question maxDateGroups will ignore the categories it doesn't show, which I do not want ...

Comment: Technically it won't ignore them, but aggregate them according to the [series.aggregate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.aggregate) option, but I get you want them to all be visible. If you know your series is recorder every 30 minutes, do `categoryAxis: { baseUnit: "minutes", baseUnitStep: 30 }` - see [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/ApIWuNin).

Comment: I know this specific series is recorded every 30 minutes because I saw it was buggy and investigated, but I could get one that's recorded every 45 mins or every 20 minutes, basically I can't know in advance. But this gives me an idea : I might be able to infer from the data the rate at which it is recorded and use that. I'll post back if it works.